# Rust: performance and style of Box initialisation/conversion

Tags: performance, rust

I'm currently learning to write rust code.
As an example application I'm writing a simple calculator.
There I have the following code snippet:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Operation {
    Number(f64),
    Addition {
        left_addend: Box<Operation>,
        right_addend: Box<Operation>,
    },
    Subtraction {
        minuend: Box<Operation>,
        subtrahend: Box<Operation>,
    },
    Multiplication {
        multiplicand: Box<Operation>,
        multiplier: Box<Operation>,
    },
    Division {
        dividend: Box<Operation>,
        divisor: Box<Operation>,
    },
}

impl Operation {
    fn boxed(self) -> Box<Operation> {
        return Box::new(self)
    }
    
    fn boxedNumber(val: f64) -> Box<Operation> {
        Box::new(Operation::Number(val))
    }
}
```

What is more rust idiomatic / performant / optimized to get a Box of Number?

1. `Box::new(Operation::Number(3.0))`
2. `Operation::boxedNumber(3.0)`
3. `Operation::Number(3.0).boxed()`

I tend to like 3. the most, as it's less code to write and pretty readable.

Or is there even a better variant?

Comment: In the playground - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=922c10ac66287ca91a1ed68a6bd1f594 - first and second ways are compiled to exact same assembly, the third one is slightly different, but I'm not sure whether it is different semantically or this is some glitch in codegen.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too much detail of the `Operation` struct (not sure whether I'd design it that way), the most idiomatic way would be using the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CT%3E)/`Into` traits.

That way you don't have to write any `impl` for conversion code yourself at all.

Example:

```rust
    #[test]
    fn into_boxed() {
        use Operation::*;
        let operation = Addition {
            left_addend: Number(1.23).into(),
            right_addend: Number(2.34).into()
        };
        println!("{:?}", operation);
    }
```

Comment: I just discovered this - thanks :) I assume there is no difference in the resulting calls between variant 1 and `.into()`?  I'm also curious what would you design differently about Operation? just the naming or completely different?

Comment: I'm not deep enough into the code generation to determine whether there's any actual difference between these variants. Ideally they should all result in the same code, calling just `Box::new`. 
Regarding the `Operation` enum, I'd probably have tried to avoid mixing numbers and hard-coding all available operations inside the enum. To me an operation feels more like a `type Operation = Fn(f64, f64) -> f64` which can be added to a `Map<char, Operation>` for associating operations with symbols.